# Updating Access from Data yielded in Excel

Tags: database, excel, ms-access, reporting

I am trying to find the best way to extract report from Access into Excel and updating Access, once data has been yieled by Questionnaire participants.

The data in Access is quite complex and large (contained in a single master table - 50+ columns & 200K+ rows) - which doesn't make it easy on the eyes.

I would like to extract reports from Access (essentially a subset of data - M columns out of N). The report will be updated by individuals (i.e. values updated) and will need to be fed back into Access.

I'm looking for the most user - friendly approach to achieve the above. Does anyone have any ideas?

Ps obvious answers welcome, I am a complete Access/Excel noob - but have a background in MySQL, SQL Server.

Comment: Question is still too broad - please be more precise about the input and `The database is not normalized` suggestion.

Comment: Edited - basically there is one huge table!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i'm aware, there is no single tool to do this, if you want to create your own, i recommend you to use any .NET language, ADO.NET and Interop to read data from and into Excel. If you don't feel you want to do some .NET programming, there is a reporting tool called [DBxtra](http://www.dbxtra.com) that take Excel, Access and many databases as input and let you export data to Excel (either static or dynamic) and other formats. The route will be like this:

1.- Create your query from your Access database in DBxtra

2.- Export the results into Excel (either linked or static sheet)

3.- Let yout users update the data in Excel

4.- Use Excel macros to update the data in the Access database.

To update the access database you will need to put a macro like this into in your Excel file:

```
Sub appProb()

    On Error GoTo 1

    Dim XLTable As TableDef

    Set Db = OpenDatabase(mdbFile)
    Set XLTable = Db.CreateTableDef("tblProbTemp")

    XLTable.Connect = "Excel 5.0;DATABASE=" & xlsFile
    XLTable.SourceTableName = "tblXLProb"
    Db.TableDefs.Append XLTable

    strSQL = "Insert into tblProb Select * FROM tblProbTemp"
    Db.Execute strSQL

1:
    Err.Clear
    On Error Resume Next
    Db.TableDefs.Delete "tblProbTemp"
    Db.Close

End Sub
```

The only thing worth to note is that `tblXLProb` is named range.

Note: This macro was copied from here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/microsoft-access/51157-update-access-records-excel.html